# Why this strange code compiles and returns 1?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

Why this code compiles and returns 1?

```
int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    return ac[av] == 0;
}
```

Comment: You sure it's not av[ac] == 0 ?

Comment: @TilakMaddy Both are correct.

Comment: There must be another question answering this, anyhow (for the short space allowed in a comment): `pointer[i]` is the same than `*(pointer + i)` which is the same than `*(i + pointer)` which is the same than `i[pointer]`.

Comment: @TidyMaddy Yes, I'm sure

Comment: `ac[av]` is equivalent to `av[ac]`. Since `ac` (or `argc`) is the number of arguments passed in `av` array, you'll always get out-of-bounds access which is _undefined behavior_. 

However, it is likely that first pointer past `av` (again, it should be called `argv`) is null pointer, comparison returns true value which is coded as  `1`.

Comment: @myaut, `av[ac]` is defined to be 0/null.

Comment: @myaut: absolutely not, `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be 0. See http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2